# Why Some devices doesn't work with 'startActivity(this, MainActivity:class.java)'?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, mobile-devices

related question: [startActivity(intent) doesn't work in some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688856/startactivityintent-doesnt-work-in-some-devices)

I tested out with `LUNA(5.0.2)` from **TG&CO** and `Galaxy J5 2016(6.0.1)` from **SAMSUNG**, `PHAB 2 PRO` from **LENOVO**, `SKY IM-100` from **Pantech**.

They doesn't work with

```
startActivity(this, MainActivity::class.java)
```

```
startActivity(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
```

I guess a lot of things related to `context`. This shows this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.view.main.MainActivity
```

Try-catch doesn't work either. I tested more than 20 devices. And only those devices have the problem.

What's wrong with the devices?

Comment: have you tried check the context is null or not?

Comment: No, But I tested more than 20 devices. And only those devices have the problem. Include Pixel phones and Samsung Galaxy 9.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702179/failing-to-launch-activity-due-to-classnotfoundexception

Comment: I'm pretty sure it might happen when we copy multiple file from other package but forget to rename them on destination. It build perfectly but on runtime it lead to error.

Comment: Well, I guess It is a device specific problem because all popular phones don't have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It happened because of I used some `Interfaces` but didn't implement them completely. It had a red line at the first line of the class. I don't know how it is able to build the project. Anyway, It built the project perfectly and worked fine with popular phones. But didn't work with the phones that I mentioned above.

After fixing this problem, All the phones worked fine. If you know the reason why they work like this, Please comment.